# Send mp3 files over TCP Socket with react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, react-native, buffer

I'm trying to send a mp3 file from a TCP server running on a mobile app developed with react-native. I used the package [react-native-tcp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tcp) along with [react-native-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob) The following code sends some data but it is unreadable:

```
  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    this.updateChatter('Server Received: ' + data);
    RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream('/sdcard/Audio/tone.mp3', 'base64')
        .then((stream) => {
           console.log('readed');
             let data = new Buffer()
             stream.open()
             stream.onData((chunk) => {
                 data.concat([data, chunk])
             })
             stream.onEnd(() => {
               socket.write(data)
                 socket.end()
             })
        })
```

Comment: I just opened an issue on the original repo `react-native-tcp`

Comment: FWIW you should never assume that you will only ever see a single `data` event, otherwise you could end up reading your mp3 many times for the same socket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use encodeURI(yourData).

Thanks

Comment: Is it good practice for big files?